# How can I find the position where a certain part of a string begins?

Tags: javascript, regex

It's late, I'm really tired, I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out a simple thing.

I have a string which will be of the form

```
BROADCAST FROM x\ny\nz
```

...where `x` is a single word with no spaces or newlines, `y` is a number, and `z` is a string whose length in characters is `y`.

All I need is to find the starting index of `z` so that I may take `string.slice(indexOfZ)` instead .

What is the form of this regular expression, and how would I write it in JavaScript?

It should be to the effect of...

```
pattern = /\n[0-9]{1,}\n.*/;
var index = string.match(pattern);
```

Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Do you actually need the index or is the index a means to an end?

Comment: No, your answer was totally valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would `/^BROADCAST FROM \w+ \d+ (.+)$/` not work?

Answer (score 1):

Regexes are good and all, but in this instance why make it hard for yourself.

```
var aParts = sFullString.split("\n");
```

Edit : Looks like u just want z so :

```
var z = aParts[2];
```

Comment: Oh damn, clever idea. Very clever. I'm just tired enough to not even think of that.

Comment: I've edited out the 1st line that did a substring. You don't need it if you don't care about the value of x.

Comment: Another non-regex method would be to use [`sFullString.substr(sFullString.lastIndexOf("\n")+1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)...

Answer (score 0):

one way to find this is split the string by /

```
var myString = x\ny\nz;
var str =  myString.split('\'); //if the format is same.
```

`var index = str[2].indexOf("z")`.

There may be another solution. but this is one that currently comes in my mind.

Hope this one helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, you misunderstood. z, y, and x are placeholder variables; they don't actually appear in the string. This requires a regular expression.

Comment: we need a little bit of escaping: `"hello\\world".split("\\")`